# solidity value not set

Tags: constructor, initialization, solidity

I have the following code to create a contract.  I am using solidity 0.4.24.  The type of minPrice is string and it's 0.001 from the input.  For some reason, I am getting the value of 0 on the contract.  I see that on my front end and also, loaded the contract on remix.  Has anyone run into something similar?

```
  await factory.methods.createAccount(
    web3.utils.fromAscii(publicDataKey),
    web3.utils.fromAscii(privateDataKey),
    web3.utils.toWei(minPrice, 'ether')
  ).send({
    from: accounts[0]
  });
```

Comment: await factory.methods.createAccount(
        web3.utils.fromAscii(publicDataKey),
        web3.utils.fromAscii(privateDataKey),
        // web3.utils.toWei(minPrice, 'ether')
        web3.utils.toWei('0.001', 'ether')
      ).send({
        from: accounts[0]
      });

Comment: sending in a string also yields 0

Comment: Share the full code